# video not working in safari with django static files

Tags: html, django

It's a video page to make a website with django.
It comes out well on Chrome, but it doesn't come out on Safari... The same goes for mobile safari.
Playsinline and video tag are all correct.
Video source is the address of a video on the Internet, but it doesn't play when I import it from a static file.
Is there a solution?
If I have to encode, I also want to know the code that automatically encodes when I load a video.

Comment: What's the mime type of the video file(s)? Some file types will not be supported in certain browsers

Comment: @lain Shelvington it is .mp4...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think those kind of static files are supported with safari